# Power meter and electric bills

Tags: power, ac

Can anyone explain to me how the power meter can differentiate between the reactive power and real power? If power is current times voltage, can we assume that since reactive elements give back the current to the generators the average power for using them is zero? If this true, how come indusrtries pay for reactive current?

Comment: Most domestic loads are high power factor (close to 1) and aren't worth while metering for reactive power (kVArh). Industrial loads are much more reactive due to the amount of motors, etc. and, if uncorrected lead to higher currents and voltage drops along the lines. These are worth fixing. Financial penalties are a good way of prompting some action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reactive power that goes forth and back form generator to the load causes the additional current load on the powerline and part of this reactive power is transformed in real power by means of a heat in powerline wires, anyway it is pure waste and not needed. That's why the industry pays another bill for it, to force them to install a power factor corrector device - switching capacitor banks.

Answer (score 2):

> "...how come indusrtries pay for reactive current?"

In the USA, industries don't pay for reactive current. The major part of the bill is for real power. If they only use a little reactive current, they are not charged for it. If they use more than a specified amount, they pay an additional charge, but they are not charged at the same rate as if it were real power. The billing formulae vary from place to place and they can be somewhat complicated. The metering system is also more complicated and expensive than residential meters.

I believe that industrial customers believe that the system is fair. I expect that many energy suppliers around the world use a similar billing system for their industrial customers.

> Can anyone explain to me how the power meter can differentiate between the reactive power and real power?

If an AC voltage and an AC current waveform are multiplied point by point, the result is a waveform that is proportional to the real power. The real power waveform can then be averaged to give numeric value of real power. That is basically what electromechanical and electronic power and energy meters do. Reactive power can be measured in the same way. It is just a matter of using the inverse of either the voltage of the current. When there is a charge for reactive power in an industrial power bill, two meters are used, one for real power and another for reactive power.

Comment: It is my understanding that some industrial users correct the power factor of their load by using large capacitor banks. I don't know if the utility asks them to do this, or if it is just to reduce whatever costs are associated with reactive power.

Comment: I think that industrial users mostly install pf correction to avoid utility charges. Utilities often notify industrial customers that they can save money if they do that, and offer technical assistance, educational material etc., sometimes at no charge. Often correction is applied to individual motors or groups of motors that are used at the same time. If customers have their own transformers feeding motors they have additional incentive to reduce the transformer load to free up capacity and reduce losses.

Comment: Improving power factor at the load reduces current to the load. That in turn reduces voltage drop along the wires improving voltage stability for the load but also the whole building as the external supply voltage drops are also reduced.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Since the source of the current is the same for reactive power and real power (hot wire cable I suppose) how can we use two power meters? My guess is that apparent power is measured and then divided somehow after to two part, reactive and real. We get billed for the real part.

Comment: As I remember it, a reactive power meter is the same as a real power meter with a connection reversed. Two meters can easily be connected to the same source by connecting the voltage terminals in parallel and the current terminals in series. There are a lot of ways to measure, especially if your instrument has a microprocessor to calculate what you want rather than summing and averaging things electrically and electromagnetically. Power, real, reactive or apparent, can never be measured directly it must always be determined from voltage, current and phase angle.

Comment: @CharlesCowie The inverse is used because the instantaneous real power depends on cos and reactive power on sin? But the average of cos and sin are zero so why do we even measure it?

Comment: You are correct. It is not a 180 degree shift that is required, it is 90 degrees. For 3-phase metering, it is done with phase-shifting potential transformers. With most 3-phase metering configurations, it is matter of different instrument transformer connections. For single-phase it is done with capacitive or inductive phase-shifting circuits. With electronic meters, it is done mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Reactive power increases losses in the distribution system, so it's not cost-free.

Losses the distribution system are mostly proportional to RMS current, regardless of phase.